# How to extract and combine text and tables from PDF using AWS Textract

Tags: python, ocr, amazon-textract

I am using the [textractor](https://aws-samples.github.io/amazon-textract-textractor/index.html) package to extract the text and the table that is present in a pdf document through AWS Textract:

```
from textractor import Textractor
from textractor.data.constants import TextractFeatures

extractor = Textractor(region_name='us-east-1')
document = extractor.start_document_analysis(
    file_source="s3://<document>.pdf",
    features=[TextractFeatures.TABLES],
)

text = document.document.pages[0].text
table_csv = document.document.pages[0].tables[0].to_csv()
```

This works well. However, I want to combine in a single text string (1) the text of the page with (2)the table on the page but WITHOUT overlapping text. Right now, the `text` variable also contains the extracted text from the `table_csv` content. If I just concatenate the strings, there will be duplicated information.

Is there a clean way to remove the overlapping text to achieve this?